# Sum of two exponential distributions with same parameter

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $S, T$ be two independent random variables both with the exponential distribution and the same parameter $\lambda > 0$.

I would like to find the **density function of $S+T$**.

$S$ and $T$ both have the density function $f(t) = \lambda \cdot e^{-\lambda t}$ where $t>0$. How do I find the density function of $S+T$? I don't know how to begin, please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The density of the sum of two independent random variables is the **convolution** of their density functions.

$$f_{S+T}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_S(x)\cdot f_T(z-x)\operatorname d x$$

Comment: This is really useful to know. This is true for general independent random variables, right?

Comment: @iwriteonbananas: This is true for general independent random variables.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $\left(X_{i}\right)_{1\leq i\leq n}$
  is independant and identically distributed according to an exponential law with a parameter $\lambda>0$
 . For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$
 , we have$$\mathbb{P}\left[X_{i}\leq x\right]=1-e^{-\lambda x}.$$
 Now, it is straightforward to use the characteristic functions : if $S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$
 , then we have for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$
  $$\chi_{_{S_{n}}}\left(t\right)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\chi_{_{X_{i}}}\left(t\right)=\left(\chi_{_{X_{1}}}\left(t\right)\right)^{n}=\left(\left(1-i\lambda t\right)^{-1}\right)^{n}=\left(1-i\lambda t\right)^{-n}$$
 which is the characteristic function of a random variable that follow a gamma law of parameters $\left(n,\lambda\right)$ (I used independance and identical distribution here). Thus, the density of the law of $S_{n}$
  is the density of the gamma law (see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).

You can also show by induction that the density of the sum of INDEPENDANT random variables is the convolution of the densities.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The distribution of $Z=X+Y$ with $X$ and $Y$ independent is given by $$f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)dx$$